# Getting "Class Not Found" error while trying to set up a new JUNIT class in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, class, junit

While setting up a JUNIT class for a uni project I keep getting the following error (working in Eclipse Oxygen):

```
Class not found UnitTest
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: UnitTest
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:688)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:421)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Cant really figure out whats going on, already tried a few question-related answers like clean up the project and checking that the test is running from my project/bin folder.

Comment: Where does the UnitTest class comes from? It seems it's not on the classpoath of your project.

Comment: There exists a file named `UnitTest.class` (case matters!) within the output directory of your project?

Comment: yup.. didnt really knew what the problem was and out of frustration i deleted and reinstalled eclipse and imported the project all over again, and it worked! thank you so much for the quick replay :]